# Defining the name of a ManyToOne relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to define a django model which has many-to-one relationship with itself. It is a user profile, connected as a OneToOne field with the authentication user model. I would like to save which user (if any) was the one who referred the 'current' user to my system. This means I have the following definition:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, related_name='profile')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SpecificUserProfile(UserProfile):
    referrer = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

I saw the django defaults to naming the set of referenced models by the name of the class with a suffix _set. I believe I will be getting something along the lines of specific_user_profile_set. I would much prefer to have it named `u1.referrer` and `u2.referred` or `u2.referred_set`. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
related_name='profile'
```

This is the argument to define a name for any related field, so:

```
class SpecificUserProfile(UserProfile):
    referrer = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='referred')
```